# How to override netrw-delete behavior?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, netrw

I'm currently using Vim 8.1 on Ubuntu 18.04, and I would like to override the default behavior of **deleting local files/directories 'forever'** when using netrw.

The doc says that this plugin uses a function called `delete()` on latest versions of vim. My guess is that this function simple uses `rm` to delete files, how could I override this behavior to use e.g. a command from trash-cli or simply moving file/directory to a different folder?

Comment: Is it acceptable to remap delete keys/redefine delete commands?

Comment: Yeah totally!, I should've mentioned that, I just want to override the default behavior of pressing 'D' in netrw, ideally by just adding a few lines to my vimrc.

Answer (score 3):

Let us be not too insane :-) and provide a different solution using mappings and netrw public API.

Beware that the code is neither complete nor was tested properly!

```
" our custom delete routine
function! g:MyNetrw_DoDelete(flist)
    echom 'Deleting ' a:flist
endfunction

" setup netrw mappings (:h g:Netrw_UserMaps)
let g:Netrw_UserMaps = [['D', 'g:MyNetrw_D'], ["\<Del>", 'g:MyNetrw_D']]

" unfortunately, the visual mode is not supported by Netrw_UserMaps,
" so implement it with the help of augroup/autocmd
" (although netrw is very peculiar about its mappings,
" it seems to work okay too)
augroup MyNetrw | au!
    autocmd FileType netrw vnoremap <buffer>D :call g:MyNetrw_vD()<CR>
augroup end

" implement normal mode deletion
function! g:MyNetrw_D(islocal)
    if a:islocal
        " get selected file list (:h netrw-mf)
        let l:flist = netrw#Expose('netrwmarkfilelist')
        if l:flist is# 'n/a'
            " no selection -- get name under cursor
            let l:flist = [b:netrw_curdir . '/' . netrw#GX()]
        else
            " remove selection as files will be deleted soon
            call netrw#Call('NetrwUnmarkAll')
        endif
        " do delete and refresh view
        call g:MyNetrw_DoDelete(l:flist)
        return 'refresh'
    endif

    " this is to handle remote deletion
    " hope it works...
    call netrw#Call('RemotePathAnalysis', b:netrw_curdir)
    let l:usermach = netrw#Expose('user') . '@' . netrw#Expose('machine')
    let l:path = netrw#Expose('path')
    call netrw#Call('NetrwRemoteRm', l:usermach, l:path)
 endfunction

" implement delete over Visual range
function! g:MyNetrw_vD() range
    if isdirectory(b:netrw_curdir)
        " assume it's local dir
        " get all file names over selected lines
        let l:flist = []
        for l:lnum in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
            execute l:lnum
            call add(l:flist, b:netrw_curdir . '/' . netrw#GX())
        endfor
        " do delete and then refresh view
        call g:MyNetrw_DoDelete(l:flist)
        call netrw#Call('NetrwRefresh', 1, b:netrw_curdir)
        return
    endif

    " remote delete over visual range -- NOT IMPLEMENTED
    " Note: call() cannot supply non-trivial range,
    " so we have to process line range manually (sigh),
    " and then call `s:NetrwRemoteRmFile()` in a loop
endfunction
```

Comment: I like this answer, it changes the behavior of 'D' when attempting to delete a file with netrw, but it's still not working, it doesn't delete (or move to trash) anything yet, it just displays a message saying 'Deleting ['/home/path/to/file']. I'll try to play around with this code tho, it seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @AdrianPirela Sure, it's just an example. You asked "how to override that thing" without _exactly_ saying what it should do instead. So I won't take a guess, you know.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear, I just want to delete a file or directory using netrw in a safer way, do you have any suggestions for this?, Something like invoking a command to move a file to the trash folder. I might update this question again if needed.

Comment: @AdrianPirela This is OS/Desktop dependent, so there can't be a truly general recommendation. Perhaps, in your case (Ubuntu?) you can simply `!mv` files to `$XDG_DATA_HOME/Trash`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not supposed to be user-modifiable. But we can "hack" it:

```
" helper function to find Script Number (aka SNR)
function! GetSNR(sfile)
    " slash <-> bslash translation
    let l:sfile = exists('+shellslash') && !&shellslash ?
        \ tr(a:sfile, '/', '\') : tr(a:sfile, '\', '/')
    " get 'number:', 'scriptfile' pairs
    let l:scripts = split(execute('scriptnames'))
    " find script file of interest
    let l:pos = index(l:scripts, l:sfile)
    " return SNR or zero
    return l:pos > 0 ? str2nr(l:scripts[l:pos - 1]) : 0
endfunction

" force autoloaded script to load
call netrw#GX()

" replace script-local function s:NetrwDelete()
" bug or feature, however this works!
execute printf('function! <SNR>%d_NetrwDelete(path)',
    \ GetSNR($VIMRUNTIME . '/autoload/netrw.vim'))
    " ***** Do something instead of delete() *****
    echom 'Attempt to delete ' . a:path
endfunction
```

Comment: Just, whoa... i can decide if that’s impressive or insane :P

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Insane... Definitely insane! :-D    Has my +1.